# Recursive harmonic function returns NaN

Tags: c, tail-recursion, nan

I have written the following sample code to find the harmonic value of N. (1+1/2+1/3+...1/N). Read the comments in the code written in BOLD and help me to find why is this happening.

```
#include <stdio.h>

float harmonic(float n, float har) {

    if(n==0) {
        return 0;
    }

    if(n==1) {
        printf("%f\n", har+1.0f);***/* This prints value 1.5000*/***
        return har+1.0f;
    }else{
        harmonic(n-1, (har+(1/n)));
    } 
} 

int main() 
{ 
    printf("%f\n", harmonic(2, 0.0f)); **/* But this prints value nan(Not a  Number)*/**  
    return 0; 
}
```

Thanks,
Naga

Comment: Naga - always make sure to compile with warnings enabled (gcc - `-Wall`, MSVV - `/Wall`).  The compiler would have warned you about your problem.

Answer (score 10):

I think you want to do:

```
return harmonic(n-1, (har+(1/n)));
```

Answer (score 2):

My first thought was that you should almost never compare floats with simple equality so "if(n==0)" should be "if(n<=EPSILON)" and "if(n==1)" should be "if(n<= 1.0f + EPSILON)" where EPSILON is a small positive fraction, maybe 1.0e-5. Depends on how much precision you can depend on.

But then I realized that n should be an int. Cast it to a float before the division. As the comparisons with "n" stand you risk infinite recursion.

Consider using a double instead of a float.

Matthew Flaschen's answer gets to real reason you get the NaN message. The original code doesn't return anything from the "else" so the caller is probably reading garbage from the stack. Hence, the NaN.